# Angular 2/4 - Show HTML document in a modal window

Tags: angular

I want to display a complete html page inside a angular component. I have tried using Sanitizing, but no luck.

The service returns a complete html document including document type, head and body. Here is what I have so far:

app.component.html

```
<div [innerHtml]="htmlBody | keepHtml: 'html'"></div>
```

app.component.ts

```
this._loginService.getUserInfo()
            .subscribe(
                success => {
                    if (success) {                            
                            this.htmlBody = success._body;
                    }
                });
```

safe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml, SafeStyle, SafeScript, SafeUrl, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';


@Pipe({ name: 'keepHtml', pure: false })
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
}

    public transform(value: string, type: string): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
    switch (type) {
        case 'html':
            return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
        case 'style':
            return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
        case 'script':
            return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
        case 'url':
            return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
        case 'resourceUrl':
            return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
        default:
            throw new Error(`Unable to bypass security for invalid type: ${type}`);
    }
}
}
```

The result is below:

[image]

where as I am expecting this:

[image]

The following is the return from service:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<!-- template name: sourceid-choose-idp-adapter-form-template.html -->


<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<title>Select Authentication System</title>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<base href="XXXX"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css" />
</head>

<body>

<div class="ping-container">

<!-- 
if there is a logo present in the 'company-logo' container,
then 'has-logo' class should be added to 'ping-header' container.
-->
<div class="ping-header">
<span class="company-logo"><!-- client company logo here --></span>
Select Authentication System
</div><!-- .ping-header -->

<div class="ping-body-container">
<form method="GET" action="/as/0u6NO/resume/as/authorization.ping">

<div class="firstcut">
<div class="ping-messages">
<div>
Please select an authentication system to verify your identity.
</div>
</div>
<div class="ping-input-container ping-input-label">
<label class="input-select">
<span class="label-text">
Select authentication system:
</span>
<div class="input-container">
<div class="wrapper">
<select name="pfidpadapterid">
<option value="ad..HTMLFormAdapter">HTMLFormAdapter</option>
<option value="ad..Kerberos">Kerberos</option>
<option value="ad..OLBTo9spokesDev">OLBTo9spokesDev</option>
<option value="ad..OLBTo9spokesSdf">OLBTo9spokesSdf</option>
<option value="ad..OLBToIntuitDev">OLBToIntuitDev</option>
<option value="ad..OLBToIntuitSdf">OLBToIntuitSdf</option>
<option value="ad..OLBToWaveDev">OLBToWaveDev</option>
<option value="ad..OLBToWaveDev1">OLBToWaveDev1</option>
<option value="ad..OLBToWaveSdf">OLBToWaveSdf</option>
<option value="ad..OLBToYodleeDev">OLBToYodleeDev</option>
<option value="ad..OLBToYodleeSDF">OLBToYodleeSDF</option>
<option value="ad..RefIDDemoLogin">RefIDDemoLogin</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
</label>
</div>
<label class="remember-selection">
<div class="ping-checkbox-container stacked">
<input type="checkbox" name="rememberChoice" value="true" checked />
<div class="icon"> </div>
Remember selection
</div>
</label>
</div>
<div class="ping-buttons">
<input type="submit" class="ping-button normal" value="Continue" title="Continue"/>
</div>
<div class="hidden-fields" style="display:none;">
</div>
</form>
</div><!-- .ping-body-container -->

<div class="ping-footer-container">
<div class="ping-footer">
<div class="ping-credits"></div>
<div class="ping-copyright">Copyright © 2003-2018. Ping Identity Corporation. All rights reserved.</div>
</div> <!-- .ping-footer -->
</div> <!-- .ping-footer-container -->

</div><!-- .ping-container -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by using the following code:

app.component.html

```
<iframe id="fred" width="100%" height="750"></iframe>
```

app.component.ts

```
this._loginService.getUserInfo()
            .subscribe(
                success => {
                    let s = document.getElementById('fred');
                    s.contentDocument.write(success._body);
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use an `iframe` and set the src to the url. You have a full document from the server, you will never get it render as you wish since it uses the HEAD and BODY tags which already exist inside the document.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following mock url: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xnciq7

Bind the response data to the DOM using [innerHtml] property

```
<hello [innerHtml]="data"></hello>
...
data = `<!doc type html>
      <html>
        <body>
          <h1>Welcome</h1>
        </body>
      </html>`;
```

Better to use Custom crafted, Bootstrap or Material Popup component.